# Iterate over list of JSON objects

Tags: python, json, sorting, iterator

I a have JSON file that contains a list likes this:

```
"locales": {
    "de": {
        "default": {
            "vegetables": [
                "apple", 
                "melon", 
                "grape", 
                "pear"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "fr": {
        "default": {
            "vegetables": [
                "apple", 
                "melon", 
                "grape", 
                "pear"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "nl": {
        "default": {
            "vegetables": [
                "apple", 
                "melon", 
                "grape", 
                "pear"
            ]
        }
    },
(...)
}
```

I would like to iterate over the `locales` ad manipulate `vegetables` depending on the locale (de, fr, nl etc.). How can I achieve that with python?

I tried something like

```
import json 

_MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_DE = [
    "pear",
    "grape",
    "apple",
    "melon"]

_MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_NL = [
    "melon",
    "pear",
    "apple",
    "grape"]

def updateJsonFile():
    jsonFile = open('vegetables.json', 'r') 
    data = json.load(jsonFile) 
    jsonFile.close() 

    for item in data["locales"]:
        if item == "de":
            item["default"]["vegetables"] = _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_DE
        elif item == "nl":
            item["default"]["vegetables"] = _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_NL
        else:
            ## do nothing ##

        with open('sortedvegetables.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

def main():
    updateJsonFile()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately this does not work but there is now error in terminal after I executed the script. `sortedvegetables.json` looks exactly the same like `vegetables.json`

Comment: Can you be able to make it more clear ? Unable to understand what you are really looking at? Give some clear examples !

Comment: Also show what is _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_DE and _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_NL

Comment: Where do you call `updateJsonFile` ?

Comment: I edited and pasted my full python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your answer:

You made some logical glitches in your code.

1) You were trying to compare as list.

```
if item == ["de"]:
```

It should be: `if item == "de":`

2) You were trying to update as `item["default"]["vegetables"]` , It is not right way, it should be written as `data["locales"]["de"]["default"]["vegetables"]` or `data["locales"]["nl"]["default"]["vegetables"]` appropriately.

```
import json

_MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_DE = [
    "pear",
    "grape",
    "apple",
    "melon"]

_MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_NL = [
    "melon",
    "pear",
    "apple",
    "grape"]

def updateJsonFile():
    jsonFile = open('vegetables.json', 'r')
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

    for item in data["locales"]:
        print(item)
        if item == "de":
            print(item)
            data["locales"]["de"]["default"]["vegetables"] = _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_DE
        elif item == "nl":
            print(item)
            data["locales"]["nl"]["default"]["vegetables"] = _MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_NL
        else:
            print("test")
            pass

        with open('sortedvegetables.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

def main():
    updateJsonFile()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what JSON is.  There is no inherent order in a dictionary; attempting to sort the entries is pointless.

Python in earlier versions would dump out the internal `dict` in whichever order the interpreter happened to have stored it internally, no matter how much you sorted it.  With the latest Python version, you can expect the dict to come back in the order you created it ... but the JSON semantics are still, in the end, a representation which does not have any order for a dictionary.